# Disable button based on default select value

Tags: javascript

I have my Javascript code where I am enabling or disabling the button with id "editsaveBtn" based on my value in the select dropdown menu. The select drop down is wrapped in div tag with id "cardExpired". But this happens only when change event happens.

```
$("#cardExpired").on('change',function(){
       if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="Select a Value")
           $("#editsaveBtn").attr('disabled',true)
       else
           $("#editsaveBtn").attr('disabled',false)
});
```

I would like the add the code to disable the button when the page loads for the first time and value in drop down is "Select a Value".

Please suggest how I can write this code

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more code, like HTML, so that we can play with it and see what is wrong.

Comment: just add the disabled attribute to the button tag on your HTML and toggle when needed like what you have

Answer (score 2):

just add the disabled attribute to the button tag on your HTML so that on load or by default it is disabled and is enabled on change of the drop down value when needed like what you have

```
<button type="button" disabled>Your button</button>
```

Comment: This should happen on page load depending on the value of dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to raise the change event when the page loads. You can do this by using chaining.

```js
$("#cardExpired").on('change',function(){
       if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="Select a Value")
           $("#editsaveBtn").attr('disabled',true)
       else
           $("#editsaveBtn").attr('disabled',false)
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="cardExpired">
<option>Select a Value</option>
<option>Value 2</option>
</select>
<button id="editsaveBtn">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will easily get code help for your problem but if try to think in terms of client side programming, you were already able to do it once on `onchange` event.

So now you just have to impersonate same on `$(document).ready()`.

Try that. Good luck.